# What is the use of the unused Data pins of a LCD

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

I've a 16 pin LCD. The whole display (16x2) can be driven just using only half of the data pins (D4 - D7) of the LCD. Other 4 data pins (D0 - D3) can be neglected.

I need to know why then the LCDs come with eight data pins. Of course, there should be some reason(achieve faster update rates etc...)

Can someone show me the reason..
*(This is just for my knowledge)*

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about LCDs, but at least for things like ROMs and RAM, usually there are extra "unused" pins for a particular part number so that it maintains pin-compatibility with the particular part family

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It has 8 data pins. The 8-bit mode is the standard mode, because the data is 8-bit: the characters are ASCII, and the DDRAM addresses are also 7 bit wide. In 8-bit mode you write them in 1 instruction, in 4-bit mode you have to split a byte in 2 nibbles, shift one of them 4 bits to the right, and perform 2 write operations.

8-bit mode is just more simple.

**edit**
The 4-bit mode is often used today to save I/O pins. When the HD44780 was released microprocessors were far more common than microcontrollers. Microprocessors have data and address buses, and since most microprocessors were at least 8-bit that was not a problem, pinning-wise. And 4-bit microprocessors used the 4-bit mode. The control signals like R/W were also available, and the register/data select was derived from an address decoder, so that the LCD became memory mapped.

Most of today's microcontrollers don't have an external databus, and access the LCD through I/O pins through which the databus and the control signals are emulated. Smaller microcontrollers often don't have I/O to spare, and for those the 4-bit mode is a good solution.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it should be 8 data pins, not 7 (i edited the post). Thanks, well explained. 8-bit mode is simple and **faster** i guess. Performance is  what matters for the user, isn't it..

Comment: @Anubis - I didn't mention speed because it's not that relevant. It would be if you had to write large amounts of data, but this is a question of a couple of bytes, and then nothing for seconds if you want the user to be able to read it.

Comment: It's hard to predict motivations - for production I once switched from a convenient serial interface used on the prototype (which I connected with my handy wire-wrap tool) to a 14-wire parallel interface converted from SPI by spare FPGA capacity, only because our purchasing department couldn't seem to obtain the matching miniature connector for the serial, while the parallel was a standard 2x7 100-mil header.  (We did not want to modify the displays by soldering to them)

Comment: @Chris - Isn't this a comment to supercat's answer?

Comment: It likely could be, but I hand't yet read that at the time.

Comment: Modern processors often require extra circuitry or pins to interface to HD44870-style LCDs even in systems that have an external memory bus, because modern buses generally run too fast to satisfy the HD44870's sample and hold times.  The HD44870 really is from another era, though it remains oddly popular.  Incidentally, do you like my idea for adding a serial-communication option without breaking compatibility?

Comment: @supercat - I surely would like to see more LCDs with serial interface, but I'm not sure I would need the compatibility. I think most users will choose for the serial interface and not care about the parallel. The HD44780 will stay with us for a while still, so an I2C version of it would certainly be nice! And talking about compatibility: how about a dual I2C/SPI interface?

Comment: @stevenvh: The HD44780 has a lot of market momentum, and I don't see module manufacturers wanting to use any chips that aren't HD44780-compatible unless or until some other standard is established.  If a chip vendor produced a cost-competitive chip which combined HD44780 compatibility with an option to use some other mode, *without requiring any special action on the part of the module makers*, then the special modes available on such modules might appeal to end-product designers enough for those modes to become part of a new de-facto standard.

Comment: @stevenvh: The way I've described, a display could use three wires as unidirectional SPI, or it could strap the /CS wire low and use repeated hits on the data wire for framing (thus only needing two wires).  I like I2C, but I think it would be hard to design a module which was fully HD44780-compatible and I2C compatible without adding extra pins.

Comment: @stevenvh: Upon further consideration, it might be possible, but I'm not sure I like it.  D0-D7 are allowed to vary at any time in any sequence, provided only that setup/hold times are met around a falling edge on E, and RS and R/W may vary freely as well while E is low.  One could design a chip so that it shouldn't accidentally detect a valid I2C addressing sequence from any legal series of bus events, but I'm not sure how to ensure that the module wouldn't be disruptive to a bus it inhabited if it powered up in a wonky state.

Answer (score 4):

Nearly character LCDs which show no more than 40 columns or 4 rows, and which have a built-in controller, almost always use a controller whose design is based on a chip called the HD44870.  That chip is designed to be usable on the bus of a 4-bit or 8-bit microprocessor running at the speeds that were common in the late 1970's or early 1980's.  The chip accepts  8-bit commands, and processes 8-bit data, but includes some extra hardware to allow data or commands to be sent as two 4-bit pieces.

Today, there are many microcontroller-based systems which do not have an exposed data bus; the preferred display connection is six pins: D4-D7, RS, and E; all other wires get strapped high or low as appropriate.  On most of the machines the chip was originally designed to interface with, however, the system bus would naturally include D0-D3 and a line that can be used for R/W (when interfacing with e.g. a Z80, one must use an address line rather than /WR to get proper timing); if the display was on a board with an early-1980's CPU bus, wiring all eleven pins would allow things to things work better than if one wired only six, with no "cost" beyond the copper traces.

I find it interesting that no competing standard has emerged for a text-only display with something like a two-wire or three-wire interface.  I would think that even if a vendor didn't want to go out on a limb selling displays that weren't compatible with the HD44870, one could design an HD44870 controller so that if e.g. it received a sequence of eight 00000000 and 11111110 commands (neither of which is valid on the HD44870) with D0 staying low the whole time and without D7 having more than two consecutive rising edges between bytes) it would interpret the sequence as an 8-bit command (using data bits from D7); additional sequences of eight bytes would be interpreted as 8-bit data.  One would send another command either by raising and reasserting D0, or by wiggling D7 three or more times.  Users of such displays could interface them with 2 or 3 wires, saving cost, but the displays would be compatible with systems that expect an HD44870.  Curious that's never happened, given that today's microcontrollers are so different from the ones for which the displays were designed.